# Syntax for value in component

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, html

I'm setting the value for a component on a VF page and I'm getting an error.  Heres the text where I'm setting the value:

```
Value="{!if(p.pricing.job_size__c.contains('1'),1,0)}"
```

It's throwing an error on the contains part.  Can't I do a check this way?  Is there something similar that'll give me what I'm looking for in this code?  I need to check if the `job_size__c` field has a 1 or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **[`Visualforce Functions`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm)**, specifically `CONTAINS`:

> **Function**
> `CONTAINS`
>
> **Description**
> Compares two arguments of text and returns TRUE if the first argument contains the second argument. If not, returns FALSE.
>
> The following example checks the content of a custom text field named Product_Type and returns “Parts” for any product with the word “part” in it. Otherwise, it returns “Service.”
>
> ```
> {!IF(contains(opportunity.Product_Type__c, "part"), "Parts", "Service")}
> ```
>
> This function is case sensitive so be sure your `compare_text` value has the correct capitalization.
>
> **Syntax**
> `CONTAINS(text, compare_text)` and replace `text` with the text that contains the value of `compare_text`.